# How to preserve pep power?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

I got a quest to perform a special move that requires three party members be be pepped up at the same time.

Now that's nearly impossible to achieve, since the pep power appears randomly, and goes away after few turns.

I tried to only Defend with the pepped up character, but the pep power goes away even so.

Is there any way to preserve pep power?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can switch your party around. This quest is very luck dependent in the early game. Later, you can get a couple of members "fired up" and switch them out. Once you're ready with 3 characters close, switch them all in and they will pep up together.

Comment: Well, I got only four characters total. so if I remove two prepped up I'll stay with only two. Guess I'll survive with items but it'll be tough... also, is this even possible?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's possible, but it is much easier to do further in the game. I recommend skipping this until you get more party members when it gets much easier.

Comment: So basically, when you have somebody pepped up and you want to keep them pepped, switch them out and as long as you keep them out the 'pep turns' will not count?

Comment: @Fredy31 yeah, don't worry about it doing it in the beginning of the game, it's much easier later.

Answer (score 1):

FoxMcCloud is right that it's a lot easier to do when you can switch people out.  What I found to help is trying to make the party members "use up" their pep as soon as possible -- by using pep powers if they have them -- so that when the next character get's their pep, it is more likely to lineup with the other characters.  Early on (when you only have 4 or fewer characters) "fired up" seems to happen sooner, so this works fairly well.  Also, keep in mind that many pep powers that require 3 people do not require them to all be pepped up.